# Where are Vote to Close buttons for questions on GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, status-completed

When I view a question on GIS Stack Exchange, the "close" or "vote to close" link/button appears to be missing.

Did this get removed on GIS Stack Exchange?

I have a rep of 451 (at the time I post this) and the FAQ says the minimum rep is 250.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

250 is for your own question, 3000 is minimum for any question.

With only 9 users currently over 3000 rep, it might take a while to get the 5 required votes.

Comment: In the absence of the button, you can flag it for a moderator to check, at least until you rack up the 3k rep.